# How to mock a method in PowerMock?

Tags: junit, mocking, powermock

I'm using PowerMock 1.4.12 and JUnit 4.8.1.  I'm having a problem getting a method to return the data I want it to.  I have

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    ...
    userService = createMock(UserService.class);
    loginController.setUserService(userService);
    …
}

@Test
public final void testAuthenticateForLoggedInAdmin()
{
    authorities.add(adminAuthority);

    final User user = new User();
    user.setUserName("userName");
    user.setPassword("password");
    user.setFirstName("firstName");
    user.setMiddleName("middleName");
    user.setLastName("lastName");
    user.setUrl("localhost");
    user.setId("id1");
    final TestsubcoAuthenticationUser principal = new TestsubcoAuthenticationUser(user.getUserName(), 
                                                                                              user.getPassword(),
                                                                                              true, 
                                                                                              true, 
                                                                                              true, 
                                                                                              true, 
                                                                                              authorities, 
                                                                                              user.getFirstName(), 
                                                                                              user.getLastName(),
                                                                                              user.getMiddleName(), 
                                                                                              user.getUrl(), 
                                                                                              user.getId(),
                                                                                              null,
                                                                                              null,
                                                                                              null);
    authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, new Object(), authorities);

    securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
    mockStatic(SecurityContextHolder.class);
    expect(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).andReturn(securityContext);
    expect(userService.findByUsernameAndUrl(user.getUserName(), user.getUrl())).andReturn(user);
    ...
    String result = loginController.authenticate();
```

but when my method in question gets called from within the controller,

```
        final User user = userService.findByUsernameAndUrl(sbUser.getUsername(), sbUser.getUrl());
```

the return value is null instead of the object I specified.  Any theories behind why this is or suggestions for troubleshooting further?  I have verified through debugging that the String parameter values passed in the controller are the same as what I specify in the "expect" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did not call `replay` on your mocks.

[replay](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5/apidocs/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.html#replay%28java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
but when my method in question gets called from within the controller,
```

I am not sure what your mean, *method in question gets called from within the controller*.
When you call the method ,your **userService** object should be the same object which you mocked. also check the argument value if same.

I you dont find this usefull, share more detail in what your trying to unit test here.